# Какая пунктуация в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, недопустимая-метка

Какая пунктуация в данном предложении? А именно какой(ие) знак(и) должна стоять после местоимения "их"? 
Это ведь не прямая речь, но и запятую тут не поставишь, что нужно? Тире? И почему?

> Однако инстинкт, заложенный
> матерью-природой, подсказывал им
> напрасно рисковать нельзя.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Однако инстинкт, заложенный матерью-природой, подсказывал им: напрасно рисковать нельзя." Это бессоюзное сложное предложение, вторая часть раскрывает содержание того, о чем говорится в первой части этого сложного предложения

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, вы мне очень помогли!:)